# iOS 5 Storyboard Orientation does not work

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, ios5, xcode4.4

We have an app we are designing using iOS 5 storyboards (Xcode 4.4, Mountain Lion) with a tab view controller and we're trying to add a split view controller as a third tab.

Prior to adding the Split View Controller, we set all the view controllers to landscape orientation in the simulated metrics section of the storyboard editor.  Worked fine.  Added the Split View Controller, changed its orientation to landscape, and the first tab (not the split view) now draws all the UI elements as if it's portrait when we run it in the simulator.  The simulator defaults to landscape, but the UI is sideways as if it was portrait, with most of it hidden (because it's designed to be landscape).

We deleted the Split View Controller and the problem persists.

Any ideas?  We've cleaned, re-built, quit Xcode, re-run, etc.  There has not been one stitch of code added yet, as we are simply trying to build the UI appearance before writing code to back it up, and we're at the very early stages.

Thanks.

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer here for the steps to make sure you have a landscape oriented app all around.

[When I click the back button my view changes from landscape to portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798808/when-i-click-the-back-button-my-view-changes-from-landscape-to-portrait/11799096#11799096)

Also Split View Controllers have to be the rootViewController. Adding them as a tab inside a TabViewController won't work out of the box.

Comment: Thanks.  I was unaware of that.